# What is the difference between STACK and TOP_STACK?

Tags: arm, stack, keil

I am using **µVision IDE - Keil**, and there is a .map file, which includes an Image Symbol Table.

I am confused with "STACK" and "TOP_STACK". (Image below)

Why isn't the "TOP_STACK" pointing at the same address as "STACK"? Assuming the program has just been initialised. Are there any data stored in the stack initially that needs 512 bytes of space?

[image: Snippet of .map file]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To anyone finding out the answer to this,

I forgot to mention that it's showing the information of an ARM Cortex-M1 processor.

For ARM Cortex-M1 processors, the stack is a DESCENDING stack, and I've declared the stack having 512 bytes of space. Therefore, TOP_STACK is pointing to the first availble space. The stack does not store any data at this point of time.

Answer (score 2):

STACK is the start of the stack. Here it is located at 0x20000000. TOP_STACK is the first available address after the stack. Here the stack is 512 bytes long (0x200 in hex). The next available address is 0x20000000 + 0x200 = 0x20000200. You can see that TOP_STACK is 0x20000200.
This often tells the linker where data can be placed in RAM or where the heap can start.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have found the correct answer. I forgot to mention that this simulator is showing the properties of ARM Cortex-M1. My bad.